# Add Folder title to header in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a document library with folders in it. When the user opens the folder, I would like to see an indication (header?) signifying to them what folder they are in. Currently they get no indication what folder they are viewing. For example, we have Processes, Procedures, Standards, Forms and Templates, and Reports in the document library and would like to see the wording of the folder display somewhere on the page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a customized master page with no navigation , the v4.master does display the navigation . But time being to answer you , the URL has query string with Rootfolder parameter which specifies the folder you are in . You can create a webpart to get the query string value and modify it to display on your master page .

OR

SharePoint 2010 has the "Navigate Up" control that appears as a folder icon next to the Site Actions menu and this provides access to the full current path with folder name